# Mouse dragging an element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, mouseevent

I've been waiting to ask this question for a long time, but couldn't, because I knew I would get bad reputation. This post was very hard to post, but I **REALLY** need this code...

Let's say there was a draggable element with the ID of "dragme"... You have to drag and drop the element to a specific spot. I was wondering if there is a code that does this task automatically for me when I execute a function. Lets name that function "dropElement". I am trying to drag "dragme" to my mouse position with a "dragElement" function with jquery or js.

This is what I tried:

```
    (function() {
    'use strict';

    var mouseX = 0;
    var mouseY = 0;
    var timer = 0;
//tracks mouse position
    document.body.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {mouseX = e.clientX; mouseY = e.clientY;});
    function dropElement() {
        $("#dragme").trigger($.Event("mousedown", {button: 0}));
        $("body").trigger($.Event("mouseup", {button: 0, clientX: mouseX, clientY: mouseY}));
        timer = setTimeout(drop, 100);
    }
dropElement() //executes function and drops "dragme" to mouse position
```

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to achieve? Do you want to move the element programatically, or do you still want to have a drag and drop behaviour ?

Comment: I want it to have a drag and drop behavior

Answer (score 1):

I hope this sample helps you

```js
var drag = {
   elem: null,
   x: 0,
   y: 0,
   state: false
 };
 var delta = {
   x: 0,
   y: 0
 };
 function dropElement(e){
   var cur_offset = $("#autoDrag").offset();
   $("#autoDrag").animate({
       left: (e.pageX),
       top: (e.pageY )
     });
 }
 $(document).mousedown(function(e) {
 dropElement(e);
 })
 $("#dragMe").mousedown(function(e) {
     drag.elem = dragMe;
     drag.x = e.pageX;
     drag.y = e.pageY;
     drag.state = true;
 })
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
   if ( drag.state) {
     delta.x = e.pageX - drag.x;
     delta.y = e.pageY - drag.y;

     var cur_offset = $(drag.elem).offset();
     $(drag.elem).offset({
       left: (cur_offset.left + delta.x),
       top: (cur_offset.top + delta.y)
     });

     drag.x = e.pageX;
     drag.y = e.pageY;
   }
 })
 $("#dragMe").mouseup(function() {
    drag.state = false;
 })
```

```css
#dragMe {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  padding:10px;
  background-color: #00a1ff;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
#autoDrag {
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align:center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  padding:10px;
  background-color: #ff00ff;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="dragMe">DragMe!</span>
<span id="autoDrag">Click somewhere I will be there!</span>
```

Comment: I'm not trying to get a draggable element, I'm trying to make a code that automatically drags and drops the dragme element to your mouse position

Comment: So you want whatever you clicked the dragme element move to there?

Comment: I updated the answer. I hope it has been helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I found the code in the question a bit complex to follow, especially with a timing function.

Instead I've gone back to basics (and vanilla JS) to think about the sequence of events. The user moves the mouse, we aren't interested unless they have put the mousedown within the element we want to drag. So this snippet sets a variable isDown which is set to true when the user puts the mouse down on the element.

Then it looks for a mousemove event on the whole window and if isDown is set it moves the element.

We also look for the mouseup event on the window and unset isDown.

The reason for looking for some events on the actual element and some on the window is because things are moving - the mouse may get out of the window before it is released for example.

```js
let isDown = false;
const dragMe = document.querySelector('.dragme');
dragMe.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
  isDown = true;
});
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
  isDown = false;
});
window.addEventListener('mousemove', function() {
  if (isDown) {
    dragMe.style.top = event.clientY + 'px';
    dragMe.style.left = event.clientX + 'px';
  }
});
```

```css
.dragme {
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  background-color: cyan;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="dragme">Drag me</div>
```

Comment: I'm not trying to get a draggable element, I'm trying to make a code that **automatically** drags and drops the dragme element to your mouse position

Comment: When does it know to do the drop because if it just always goes to the mouse position it will never be dropped, it will just follow the mouse around (which, incidentally, is easier to achieve as you don't have to remember any states).

Comment: Thank you for a non-jQuery answer.